# Multiple columns in TOC and Legend in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I would like to give the user additional information next to the label in the TOC of a UniqueValueRenderer for each class. I can just add the numbers in the labeltext, but it does not align to proper columns. 
Is there a way to achive an alignment or display an extra column for the classes of the UniqueValueRenderer (with arcobjects)?

[image: TOC in Arcmap: The numbers need to be aligned]

[image: Achiving columns using a monospace font in layout view]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or two of how it is now and how you want it?

Comment: Not sure if there's a good way to do this. A (quite ugly) workaround would be to create two new legends with layers displaying the reqired values only and no symbols, which you then can align yourself in the right position.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is a valid workaround for the print view. Unfortunatly the user experience in the TOC is not as pleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to get columns in the TOC, but the legend updates.
I used several basic text fields for the columns and gave them names in the properties.
In the code I update them when the user switches to the layout view:

```
IGraphicsContainer container = (IGraphicsContainer) pView;
container.reset();
IElement docElement = container.next();
while (docElement != null)
{
    if (docElement instanceof ITextElement )
    {
    ITextElement textElem = (ITextElement) docElement;
        if (elemProp.getName().equals("columnname"))
        {
            textElem.setText("some text for the column");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```